# How do I convert a PivotTable that was made into Pandas / Numpy in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot-table

In python3 and pandas I have this dataframe:

```
despesas_atuais_final.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 82318 entries, 0 to 82317
Data columns (total 18 columns):
Ano                     82318 non-null object
CNPJ                    82318 non-null object
Deputado                82318 non-null object
Fornecedor              82318 non-null object
Matricula               82318 non-null int64
Mes                     82318 non-null int64
Tipo                    82318 non-null object
Valor                   82318 non-null float64
cnpj_raiz_fornecedor    82318 non-null object
codigo_unico            82318 non-null object
nome_deputado           82318 non-null object
uf                      82318 non-null object
nome_completo           82318 non-null object
sequencial              82318 non-null object
cpf                     82318 non-null object
nome_urna               82318 non-null object
partido_eleicao         82318 non-null object
situacao                82318 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(15)
memory usage: 11.9+ MB
```

The column "Valor" are expense values. The column "nome_deputado" has names of people who made expenses. The "Ano" is the year of the expense. And "Mes" is the month of the expense, in numbers.

I made a PivotTable to know how much each person's monthly expenditure each year:

```
pd.pivot_table(despesas_atuais_final,index=["nome_deputado","Ano", "Mes"], values=["Valor"], aggfunc=np.sum)

                                Valor
nome_deputado   Ano     Mes     
ABELARDO CAMARINHA  2015    3   3,345.40
4   4,843.97
5   15,738.48
6   18,245.08
7   23,953.70
8   27,587.43
9   27,058.59
10  24,117.43
11  20,984.07
2016    2   12,008.00
3   28,415.86
4   24,187.94
5   27,776.08
6   26,755.00
7   26,478.03
8   29,930.60
```

...

Please, there is a way to turn this PivotTable into a dataframe? Like this:

```
nome_deputado       Ano     Mes     Valor
ABELARDO CAMARINHA  2015    3   3,345.40
ABELARDO CAMARINHA  2015    4   4,843.97
ABELARDO CAMARINHA  2015    5   15,738.48
...
```

Comment: have you tried adding `.reset_index()` at the end of the command line `pd.pivot_...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your object in the DataFrame function

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.pivot_table(despesas_atuais_final,index=["nome_deputado","Ano", "Mes"], values=["Valor"], aggfunc=np.sum))
```

Comment: Thank you. But that did not work: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 3874 entries, (ABELARDO CAMARINHA, 2015, 3) to (WELSON GASPARINI, 2018, 5)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Valor    3874 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 42.9+ KB